# Table Height CSS and body scroll

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to set the height of a table using CSS and then allow the scroll on the body. 
The problem is that the height property does not work for table (height of the table is not equal to the size of the div container but much higher). So the table does not apply the scroll because there is enough space. Any Fix?

```css
#container{
height : 75px;
overflow:hidden;
}

#tab{
border:1px solid black;
height:100%;
}

tbody{
background-color: blue;
height:90%;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<table id="tab">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Head</td>
            <td>Head</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body</td>
            <td>Body</td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need fixed thead and only tbody to scroll?

Comment: Yes, only the body. I managed to do it without using a table and only by using divs but I don't like this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d1d3rwLg/1/)**

```
 #container {
    height : 75px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#tab {   
    border: 1px solid black;   
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #999;
}
tbody {
    background-color: #ddd;
    display: block;
    height: 44px;   
    overflow-y: auto;  
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
th,td{padding:2px 10px;
}
```

Adjust the values according to your requirement..

Comment: Hey thank, this is really working. But in my case, the height of the body and the table cannot be fixed, in order to suit different screens (computers, phones, tablets...). 
I tried your solution with a height of the body proportional to the container but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this one :

```
#container {
    height : 75px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#tab {   
    border: 1px solid black;   
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: Blue;
}
tbody {
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    height: 44px;   
    overflow-y: auto;  
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
th,td{padding:2px 10px;
}
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/d1d3rwLg/3/)

Or

[HERE MY ANOTHER ONE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/CrSpu/6360/)

Comment: Hey can I do it without fixing the height of the body (let it relative) because it has to suit any screen..